# How to handle making one and only one "primary" product ID per product

Tags: django, database, django-models

Life used to be simple. We had a table of products each of which has a product code.

Unfortunately, we are a small manufacturer with relationships with several large distributors, who very much want us to use *their* product codes when they order from us (and sometimes, not even with a courtesy description for a human-type look-up!).  so it's now looking like

```
Class ProductCode( models.Model)
    item_desc = models.ForeignKey( ItemDesc, related_name=product_codes) 
    code = models.CharField( ...)
    customer = ... # FK or Character, unique with code 
    primary = models.BooleanField( ... ) # wrong way?
    ...

Class ItemDesc( models.Model)
    # code = models.CharField( ...)                         # what we used to do
    primary_code = models.OneToOneField( ProductCode, ... ) # maybe?
    ...
```

How can I make sure that there is always one and only one primary product code per ItemDesc? (Primary being the one that we use internally to refer to  items, for example in stock, and for direct sales to end-users).

Conceptually I make primary unique with item_desc but that doesn't solve two related problems

1. It would have to become an integer, with (say) 1 = primary and 2..N existing only to make non-unique and be treated like false.
2. How to make it so an ItemDesc always has a primary ProductCode?

Or, a  field `primary = OneToOneField(...)` back from ItemDesc to ProductCode would seem to describe the relationship, but there's a circularity problem. I'd have to

1. create product codes with a null item_desc, in order to save them, so
2. they could be used as 1:1 with a new ItemDesc. Then I'd have to go back and
3. fill in the item_desc in the produce code  duplicating the 1:1 relation.

I have this feeling that there must be a better way, but I cannot think of it. Or can this be hidden and DRY inside the ItemDesc model?

Comment: This is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466726/django-circular-model-reference/8549051), where your captain is the primary code. It's also what someone wanted to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909428/circular-dependency-in-django-foreignkey), and the answer was to rethink the relationships. A couple of comments in my first link mention turning off foreign key checking until the end of a transaction, but I'm not sure what that means in practice, when you're creating the objects.

Comment: On a more fundamental database level, [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102903/is-it-acceptable-to-have-circular-foreign-key-references-how-to-avoid-them) is also interesting, as is the existence of deferrable foreign key constraints, mentioned in a comment in [another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170668/enforcing-at-least-one-child-in-a-foreign-key-constraint-or-11-n-relationship#comment329694_170668).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well you want to, instead of having a unique code at ItemDesc level, refer to your client's own code of the product. In that case :

1) About your described circularity problem :

(i) you could save your ProductCode without a null ItemDesc, simply by adding `blank=True, null=True` to `item_desc`.

(ii)  `item_desc` itself doesn't look necessary in your ProductCode model : if there is a one-to-one relationship from ItemDesc to ProductCode, the reverse is true and automatically created. No need to repeat it at ProductCode level (and even less with a ForeignKey if you want this relationship to be unique).

2) I think the following is sufficient for covering your need (having your ItemDesc pointing to a unique ProductCode that is client-related) :

```
Class ProductCode( models.Model):
    code = models.CharField( ...)
    customer = ... # FK or Character, unique with code 
    ...

Class ItemDesc( models.Model):
    primary_code = models.OneToOneField( ProductCode, ... )
```

==> For a given `item`, the client-related code would be accessible as `item.primary_code.code`
==> This won't give you a unique code per product though, for example in the case that two clients have the same reference for different products : you would end up with a single code for 2 products. If you need that, you would probably need to improve the code with the automatic generation of an internal code, for ex in the ItemDesc model :

```
@property # So that you can call it simply as if it was an attribute
def internal_code(self):
    return str(self.primary_code.customer.id) + '#' + self.primary_code.code
```

`item.internal_code` would then return your internal unique code, when `item.primary_code.code` would return your client's code of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering my own question (though still not completely happy with my own answer). This seems to work:

```
class ItemDesc( models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField( max_length=40, unique=True, blank=False )
    primary_code = models.OneToOneField( 'PenBarCode', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='_primary')
    ...

    @property
    def product_code( self):
        if hasattr( self, '_new_primary_code'): return self._new_primary_code
        try:
            return self.primary_code.itemcode
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
    @product_code.setter
    def product_code( self, value):
        self._new_primary_code = value  # lazy. If this object not saved don't want primary code saved

    def save( self, *a, **kw):
        if self.pk is not None:
            # it already exists in the DB, may need also to save changed primary code
            if getattr( self, '_new_primary_code', False):
                self.primary_code.itemcode = self._new_primary_code
                self.primary_code.save()
                del self._new_primary_code
            return super().save(*a, **kw)

        # Adding new object. If we have no product_id then make one up. For demo
        if not getattr( self, '_new_primary_code', False):
            self._new_primary_code = 'Auto-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%f-%H%M')
        # create a code to be primary
        p = ProdCode( itemcode=self._new_primary_code)
        p.save()
        # now it exists we can make it our primary
        self.primary_code = p
        rc = super().save(*a, **kw)
        # and p needs updating to point back on ourself 
        p.item = self
        p.save()
        del self._new_primary_code
        return rc

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class ProdCode( models.Model):
    itemcode = models.CharField( max_length=20, unique=True, blank=True )
    item = models.ForeignKey( ItemDesc, null=True, related_name='code_set' )
    ...
#    _primary = OneToOne from ItemDesc, or None if not primary

    @property
    def primary(self):
        try:
            return self._primary
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

    def save( self, *a, **kw):
        if self.primary: 
            self.item = self.primary
        return super().save(*a, **kw)
```

`ItemDesc` has a `OneToOne` relation with one `ProdCode`. All `ProdCode` objects have a `ForeignKey` to an `ItemDesc`. So one can add extra customer-specific `ProdCode`s and use them to look up their  `ItemDesc`.

By use of a property, it's possible to make the primary `ProdCode` look as if it is still a part of the `ItemDesc` in that you can access and change it through that object. It's also possible to promote any `ProdCode` to be the primary `ProdCode` by assigning it to `item.primary_code` and saving.

I wanted to use `on_delete=PROTECT` for `ItemDesc.primary_code` but it does not seem to be easily possible to have protect and `OneToOne` working together, other than to make an object effectively un-deletable through Django after creation. Maybe I'm missing something here?