# How to save Django model instances with circular dependency?

Tags: django, django-models, circular-reference

models.py:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    last_interaction = models.OneToOneField('Interaction',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       related_name='server')

class Interaction(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="interactions")
```

How do I save instances? (When I want to save one, the other isn't saved yet, so it can't be saved)

Notes:

1. I been [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909428/circular-dependency-in-django-foreignkey). The accepted answer doesn't provide a solution to the problem. Indeed at runtime there will be new servers and clients.
2. I know this schema makes little sense, but I still want to find a way to work with this.
3. I know the `on_delete=cascade` in Server is dangerous. I plan to fix it once I solve this problem.

Comment: There are various ways to solve this; the simplest is probably to allow null to the `last_interaction` field of the `Server` model. Also notice that the `last_interaction` field is reduntant since you can extract the last interaction for a server using a Max('time') aggregate on the `Interaction` model.

Comment: @Serafeim I don't want to allow null. It's definitely a solution, but I'm hoping for something better. In response to the second part, it's there because the last interaction will be accessed every second, but interactions will be added every couple of hours.

Comment: Well as you should understand the problem cannot be solved with a database that respects referential integrity unless you allow null. Now on your other comment; if the last_interaction field is accessed every second then its not a good idea to put it in the database; use caching instead. Thus you can still use the aggregate i recommended and but put it in the cache; when you add an interaction invalidate the cache to refresh the last_interaction value.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, if you create a circular foreign key relationship, at least one of them must be nullable. For example:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="interactions",
                               null=True
    )
```

You'll be able to create `Interaction` objects without having the corresponding `Server` instance ready.

Comment: "at least one of them must be nullable" - this is semantically not necessary. Consistent database states are possible without any of the relations being nullable. It may so be that Django doesn't provide a way to go from an empty db to any such state.

Comment: It is true that there are valid database states where this is not the case, but in order to populate an empty DB, one must be nullable, or you must disable foreign key checks long enough to make the saving. Try to do it with the SQL console; you will find that it is not a Django specific problem but that it is needed in order for the creation of new rows in an empty db.

Comment: Oracle does seem to allow deferred constraint checking, although I haven't checked if it works for this exact situation.(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#i4665)